# How to add creationTime for AppEngine entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am using Objectify for Persisting entities on AppEngine.

In couple of entities, I want to store creationTime and lastUpdateTime.

My intention is that creationTime is added to an entity when it is created for the first time.
while LastUpdate time should be updated, whenever the entity is updated.

For lastUpdateTime I can easily use `@PrePersist` to attach a hook to modify the lastUpdateTime.

But whenever I do an update on entity, I want to retain creationTime.

Now one solution is to fetch the creationTime and then add it to my entity.

Is there any way where I dont have to fetch the creationTime just before every save?

I tried the combination of `@NotSaved(IfNull)` and then set creationTime to null hoping that Objectify will ignore this, but actual behaviour is that it will set creationTime=null on datastore.

For reference, my entity looks like this :

```
public class TestEntity {
  @Id
  Long id;
  Date creationTime;
  Date lastUpdateTime;
  String mutableField;
  ...
  // Constructor1
  public TestEntity(Long id, Date date, String mutableField) {
    this.id = id;
    creationTime = date;
    lastUpdateTime = date;
    this.mutableField = mutableField;
  }

  // Constructor2
  public TestEntity(Long id, String mutableField) {
    this.id = id;
    lastUpdateTime = new Date();
    this.mutableField = mutableField;
  }
}
```

Edit1 :
Sorry. I think My question was in-complete. I have modified my TestEntity definition. Let us assume that this TestEntity contains two immutable field (id, creationTime) and two mutable fields (lastUpdateTime, mutableField2).

Now depending on context, it is possible that all these five fields are sent to the client, and then client updates mutableFields and sends a request to update the mutable fields.

For simplicity of discussion, let us assume that using Session and some other way(e.g. NameSpace), we can ensure that User is allowed to modify this entity.

Now my intention is to do following :
* When entity is created for the first time, use constructor1.
* When client asks for this entity, Server sends (id and mutablefield).
* Client sends a request to update the entity with new value for mutableField alongwith Id.
* Now on the server side, I want to update the mutable field without loosing the creationTime.

Now this can be done by first fetching the entity from DataStore, then update the mutableField and then persist again. I was wondering if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use your constructor.

```
public class TestEntity {
    public TestEntity(...your normal init params...) {
        creationTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think my question did not give complete picuture so I had updated accrodingly. Your proposed solution works great as long as the entity is inside the AppEngine. But if I send this entity to Client, and client wants to modify some part of the entity,then either (a) I have to send the creationTime to client, and expect it not to modify, or (b) do a fetch from DataStore and update the fields as requested by client (without touching creationTime). I was wondering if both of these two steps can be avoided.

Comment: @Arjun When you send data to the client, you're going to have to serialize it in some format the client recognizes anyway. How you convert between that and datastore entities is entirely up to you.